# SQL not pulling expected data from different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, union-all

Data:

[image]

I need to pull the most current, nonzero, number from each month newest year first.  I first tried this:

```
Select Top(1) DfcMonth1 as [Value], year_f
FROM dfcsthmonths_mst
WHERE (item = N'A602BK') AND (type = 'B') AND DfcMonth1 <> 0
Order by year_f DESC
```

seemed to work until I did a Union then it started pulling back numbers from different years so I tried this:

```
Select Top(1) DfcMonth1 as [Value], max(year_f) as year_f, 1 AS [month]
FROM dfcsthmonths_mst
WHERE (item = N'A602BK') AND (type = 'B') AND DfcMonth1 <> 0
GROUP BY DFCMonth1
```

This also seemed to work but when I did a union for all 12 some months pull back unexpected data from wrong years.

```
Select Top(1) DfcMonth1 as [Value], max(year_f) as year_f, 1 AS [month]
FROM dfcsthmonths_mst
WHERE (item = N'A602BK') AND (type = 'B') AND DfcMonth1 <> 0
GROUP BY DFCMonth1
UNION ALL
Select Top(1) DfcMonth2 as [Value],max(year_f) as year_f, 2 AS [month]
FROM dfcsthmonths_mst
WHERE (item = N'A602BK') AND (type = 'B') AND DfcMonth2 <> 0
GROUP BY DFCMonth2
UNION ALL
Select Top(1) DfcMonth3 as [Value], max(CAST(year_f as INT)) as year_f, 3 AS [month]
FROM dfcsthmonths_mst
WHERE (item = N'A602BK') AND (type = 'B') AND DfcMonth3 <> 0
GROUP BY DFCMonth3
UNION ALL
Select Top(1) DfcMonth4 as [Value],max(year_f) as year_f, 4 AS [month]
FROM dfcsthmonths_mst
WHERE (item = N'A602BK') AND (type = 'B') AND DfcMonth4 <> 0
GROUP BY DFCMonth4
UNION ALL
Select Top(1) DfcMonth5 as [Value],max(year_f) as year_f, 5 AS [month]
FROM dfcsthmonths_mst
WHERE (item = N'A602BK') AND (type = 'B') AND DfcMonth5 <> 0
GROUP BY DFCMonth5
UNION ALL
Select Top(1) DfcMonth6 as [Value],max(year_f) as year_f, 6 AS [month]
FROM dfcsthmonths_mst
WHERE (item = N'A602BK') AND (type = 'B') AND DfcMonth6 <> 0
GROUP BY DFCMonth6
UNION ALL
Select Top(1) DfcMonth7 as [Value],max(year_f) as year_f, 7 AS [month]
FROM dfcsthmonths_mst
WHERE (item = N'A602BK') AND (type = 'B') AND DfcMonth7 <> 0
GROUP BY DFCMonth7
UNION ALL
Select Top(1) DfcMonth8 as [Value],max(year_f) as year_f, 8 AS [month]
FROM dfcsthmonths_mst
WHERE (item = N'A602BK') AND (type = 'B') AND DfcMonth8 <> 0
GROUP BY DFCMonth8
UNION ALL
Select Top(1) DfcMonth9 as [Value],max(year_f) as year_f, 9 AS [month]
FROM dfcsthmonths_mst
WHERE (item = N'A602BK') AND (type = 'B') AND DfcMonth9 <> 0
GROUP BY DFCMonth9
UNION ALL
Select Top(1) DfcMonth10 as [Value],max(year_f) as year_f, 10 AS [month]
FROM dfcsthmonths_mst
WHERE (item = N'A602BK') AND (type = 'B') AND DfcMonth2 <> 0
GROUP BY DFCMonth10
UNION ALL
Select Top(1) DfcMonth11 as [Value],max(year_f) as year_f, 11 AS [month]
FROM dfcsthmonths_mst
WHERE (item = N'A602BK') AND (type = 'B') AND DfcMonth11 <> 0
GROUP BY DFCMonth11
UNION ALL
Select Top(1) DfcMonth12 as [Value],max(year_f) as year_f, 12 AS [month]
FROM dfcsthmonths_mst
WHERE (item = N'A602BK') AND (type = 'B') AND DfcMonth12 <> 0
GROUP BY DFCMonth12
Order by [month], year_f DESC
```

Results:

```
 Value      year_fmonth
 11202.00   2016    1
 10656.00   2016    2
 15130.00   2014    3
 15551.00   2016    4
 21518.00   2016    5
 18946.00   2012    6
 13616.00   2016    7
 17026.11   2016    8
 19704.00   2014    9
     0.00   2016    10
  5045.00   2015    11
  7077.00   2015    12
```

Any ideas or suggestions?

Thank you,
Ron

Comment: Hey Ron can you put your code inside the code snips?

Comment: please add which database your are at, as tag.

Comment: SQL Server 2012

Comment: i meant you to add as a tag like `sql`, `union-all`

Comment: JNevill Thank you for the edit as I was trying to figure out how to format this to look better, that really helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Unions, the Order by is applied to the whole result set, not each individual part. Therefore the Top (1) in each section is returning a random row. Pretty sure the GROUP BY isn't required either.

It's not pretty, but try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
   (
   Select Top(1) DfcMonth1 as [Value], year_f, 1 AS [month]
   FROM dfcsthmonths_mst
   WHERE (item = N'A602BK') AND (type = 'B') AND DfcMonth1 <> 0
   ORDER BY year_f DESC
   ) x 

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM
    (
    Select Top(1) DfcMonth2 as [Value], year_f, 2 AS [month]
    FROM dfcsthmonths_mst
    WHERE (item = N'A602BK') AND (type = 'B') AND DfcMonth2 <> 0
    ORDER BY year_f DESC
    ) x 

UNION ALL

    ....

ORDER BY [Month]
```

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly.  That makes sense then why the numbers worked when I tested a single section. Thank you for the help and the education!